# Find Ram/Memory manufacturer in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, ram

I don't know the name of the manufacturer. 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF on Google search does not help either. Anyway to fetch the name? I've few other servers with different result but not the name.

Few other manufacture's code that I'm looking for its name.
80AD808980AD
830B7FB3830B
80CE808980CE

```
    [root@myserver ~]# dmidecode -t 17 > mem.txt
    [root@myserver ~]# cat mem.txt | grep "Manufacture"
            Manufacturer: 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            Manufacturer: 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            Manufacturer: 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            Manufacturer: 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            Manufacturer: 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            Manufacturer: 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            Manufacturer: 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
            Manufacturer: 2CFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's Micron Technology.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168518